# How to get nested web element in dynamic table using xpath

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have a table, which is dynamic (so I can't use strict locator or paths)

```
<tbody>
<tr class="odd" role="row">
<td>Company</td>
<td class="sorting_1">
<td>22222@222222</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>
<td>12/28/2016 04:13:10</td>
<td class=" checkbox-cell width-to-content">
<div class="checkbox">
<label>
<input class="mass-action" name="mass-action" value="" type="checkbox"/>
<span class="checkbox-material">
<span class="check"/>
</span>
</label>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="even" role="row">
<tr class="odd" role="row">
<tr class="even" role="row">
</tbody>
```

I've tried to solve it in two steps, like this:

```
WebElement row = tableBody.findElement(
By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'222222@222222')]/parent::tr"));
WebElement targetEl = row.findElement(By.className("check"));
```

But this solution is terrible and totally ineffective.

Can anyone suggest some ideas how to make it more effectively?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you want to select the `span` element with the class `check`.
You need to search for the `tr` that contains your text and continue from there.

```
//tr[.//td[contains(text(),'@')]]//span[@class='check']
```